# MySQL - Join 2 tables multiple columns

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have 2 Tables. members and pass_delivery

## Members Table Structure

id,
first_name,
last_name

## Pass Delivery Table Structure

id, member_id, member_admin_id, member_user_id, no_of_passes, status

## Relation

member_id, member_admin_id and member_user_id contains the id of member table.

## Objective

I want to display a row like below:-
ID of member Table
Name of Member
No. of Passes
Status
Member Admin Name
Member User Name

I have tried with joins but not working.. Please help.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: select 
m.first_name, m.last_name,
db.first_name, db.last_name,
da.first_name, da.last_name
from members m, members db, members da
left_outer join pass_delivery p on 
p.member_id=m.id
and p.delivery_admin_id=da.id
and p.delivery_boy_id=db.id   But its not working..

Comment: Check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join to join the two tables since they have unique id which is the id. So create a query that concatenates the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this out :***

Suppose `PassDelivery` and `Members`  are your table names

```
 select id, first_name,last_name,Information, no_of_passes,status,member_admin_id,member_user_id FROM
   Members JOIN PassDelivery ON Members.id=PassDelivery .id;
```

Comment: Yes It works.. But i need the list of members from members table and their status from pass delivery table.

Comment: You want the list of members by their names and their statuses?

Comment: Yes List of members from members table and join them on pass_delivery table. if the member_id does not exist in pass_delivery table, then i should just show a blank column.

Comment: So you mean the query i posted doesnt achieve it?, according to what you are saying , that query should be working for you may be theres some other uniqueness you want

Comment: rather joining pass_delivery on members table, i want to join members on pass_delivery table

Comment: select 
m.first_name, m.last_name,
db.first_name, db.last_name,
da.first_name, da.last_name
from members m, members db, members da
inner join pass_delivery p on 
p.member_id=m.id
inner join pass_delivery p2 on 
p2.delivery_admin_id=da.id
inner join pass_delivery p3 on 
p3.delivery_boy_id=db.id
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'm.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Why dont u neglect thos words db,m and you just pput the exact names of the Tables like pass_delivery.id

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.first_name, m.last_name, p.status, m2.first_name, m2.last_name, m3.first_name, m3.last_name from members m 
left outer join pass_delivery p on p.member_id=m.id
left outer join members m2 on m2.id=p.delivery_admin_id
left outer join members m3 on m3.id=p.delivery_boy_id
```